# How to save an Enterprise Wi-Fi Network in android 10 or later?

Tags: android, wifimanager

I am trying to save a Wi-Fi Enterprise Network in android. This code is working until Android 9 or lower but not above.

```
public static boolean connectToEnterprise(Context context, String ssid, String identity, String password) {
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

        WifiConfiguration wifiConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
        wifiConfig.SSID = "\"" + ssid + "\"";
        wifiConfig.preSharedKey = "\"" + password + "\"";

        // Set the EAP parameters
        wifiConfig.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_EAP);
        wifiConfig.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.IEEE8021X);

        wifiConfig.enterpriseConfig = new WifiEnterpriseConfig();
        wifiConfig.enterpriseConfig.setEapMethod(WifiEnterpriseConfig.Eap.PEAP);
        wifiConfig.enterpriseConfig.setPhase2Method(WifiEnterpriseConfig.Phase2.MSCHAPV2);
        wifiConfig.enterpriseConfig.setIdentity(identity);
        wifiConfig.enterpriseConfig.setPassword(password);

        int netId = wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfig);
        if (netId != -1) {
            // Save the configuration and enable it.
            wifiManager.saveConfiguration();
            wifiManager.disableNetwork(netId);
            wifiManager.disconnect();
            turnOffAndOnWifi(wifiManager);
            wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true);
            wifiManager.reconnect();
            return true;
        } else {
            // Failed to add the network configuration.
            return false;
        }


    }
```

I tried `addNetworkSuggestions` method told in in [android docs]
(https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#addNetwork(android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration)
but it connects only when network is in range and also does not save that network in the device.

## When it works

`addNetwork` method works when I set android app `targetSdk=28`. Then it also works on all devices. But then I can't upload app to playstore because to upload playstore `targetSdk` should be `31` for now.

I want it to save the Wi-Fi network in the device.